# Render to texture: always black texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying rendering to a texture and subsequently using the texture, but for some reason it doesn't work.

As described in Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html),

first I allocate the fbo for rendering to texture..

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &read_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, read_framebuffer);
```

then I create the texture and attach it to that fbo..

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8_OES, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                       texture, 0);
```

then create the fbo for drawing..

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &draw_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, draw_framebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
[_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
```

Later in the rendering loop part..

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, read_framebuffer);

(...off-screen drawing the scene here...)

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, draw_framebuffer);
```

Bind the texture which is supposed to contain my offscreen rendering image..

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

(..draw the scene with texture applied here...)
```

However, for some reason the texture is always black.. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Immediately after the call to `glFramebufferTexture2D`, what is the value returned by `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `glTexImage2D` swap `GL_RGBA8_OES` for `GL_RGBA`. I can see you took these parameters from apple documentation.. (no comment..) Anyway about the comments on your question, as @prideout pointed out, you should always check frame buffer status. In your case it returned `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`.